# How do I make my Linq to Sql entity expose an interface?

Tags: linq-to-sql, design-patterns, interface

Using Nerd Dinner as an example:

```
private NerdDinnerDataContext db = new NerdDinnerDataContext();

public IQueryable<Dinner> FindAllDinners() 
{
    return db.Dinners;
}
```

Is it not bad practice to directly expose the entity class `Dinner` here? I think it is better for the repository to return an `IDinner`.

So my question is, how can I make the auto-generated entity classes expose my interface?

Comment: You won't get this working with LINQ to SQL without losing the possibility of using LINQ queries.

Comment: @Steven: really? doesn't that kinda mean L2S really sucks then?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only way would be to modify the template from which the code is generated. Another possibility is partial classes. The code generator creates partial classes. You could create another partial class that contains the interface you want. I believe this will work.

Comment: Yeah, that, or create wrapper classes around all of the generated ones. I think maybe the Linq-To-Entities framework available with .NET 4 and Visual Studio 2010 can do this better, but I don't remember where I read it.